# How do I trigger an event to work for ctx.guild

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

For example, let's say I have a client event that I only want to trigger if said server allows it to with a command.

like

```
@bot.command()
async def allow(ctx):
    #code that makes my specified event work for the server, keep in mind there are multiple servers
```

Like do I need a JSON to keep a log of the ctx.guild.id? or?

Please mention the code in cog and normal form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to store it in a JSON file yea. And have it like : when command `allow` is executed, store the guild ID in the JSON file. When executing said allowed command, check if the guild ID is in the JSON file. If so continue, if not return.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: I gave you the gist of it, a few quick google searches and experimenting and you'll have it ready to go!

Comment: kk fine i'll try thanks man here's a big fat green

Comment: No worries dude! Best of luck getting it to work!